# flyway Working with existing Db

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I'm start to use flyway in my project, i configure to apply new changes on my db, but i want to know if can i use 2 parans `init-method="init, migrate"` because every time i want to start on a new computer i need to restore some db backup from pgadim change the ini-method to init, so he will create the table to control the updates. so then i need to change my init-method to migrate to apply future changes.

i want to know if have an better way to do this.

sorry my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway 2.1 will come with an initOnMigrate setting that does exactly what you need. Until then, you can always wrap the Flyway class with one containing the logic you need.